# How to split partition /dev/sda on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, partition, partition-table

I'm figuring how can I split partition of `/dev/sda1/` into `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` of my Ubuntu virtual box.

Right now, every time I create a new instance of Virtual Server with vagrant, I allocated 40GB of disk space to it and all of the disk spaces is alloted to `/dev/sda1`

I need a way to split `/dev/sda1` partition into 2 with terminal (remote ssh).

So what I've tried so far is

```
// Step 1
root@server-1:~# fdisk /dev/sda

// Step 2 Delete sda1
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.

// Step 3 Create 2 new Partition
Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p):p
Partition number (1-4, default 1):
First sector (2048-83886079, default 2048):
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-83886079, default 83886079): 61440000

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 29.3 GiB.
Partition #1 contains a ext4 signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: N
Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (2-4, default 2):
First sector (61440001-83886079, default 61442048):
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (61442048-83886079, default 83886079):

Created a new partition 2 of type 'Linux' and of size 10.7 GiB.

// Step 4 and last step is write it to disk
Command (m for help): w
```

So this way works as I want, but if I ran a fsck on `/dev/sda1` I get an invalid checksum on the filesystem and whenever I rebooted the vm, the SSH refused to connect. It didn't even respond.

Is what I do correct ? is the partition corrupted ? is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: you deleted an existing primary partition from the partition table and then created new but smaller one and a new one on the tail of the new one ?  and expected to be able to use the old one .... you can do the same thing when expanding a partition ! but not in this way. ext4 doesn't like losing space on the end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you're missing the first step. You first have to shrink the filesystem on partition sda1, before shrinking the partition itself. Shrinking filesystems is not always supported, and is inherently dangerous (just as this whole operation is). My suggestion is to shrink the filesystem to a bit less than you want to shrink the partition to, then re-grow the filesystem after you've shrunk the partition.